# how to sync any type of data between a server and clients(mobile and other)?

Tags: client-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a multi-clients environment, and i would like to sync between the client to the server both ways (server->client & client->server)

do you know of anything that can get me started on this horrified task?
i have multiple requirments:

1. the data to be synced can be very different (files, messages (inbox), status of messages (read, replied and etc..)
2. the changes to this data can happen both on the client and on the server.
3. the changes can happen even if there is no communication between the server and the client. (they are responsible on syncing the differences when the communication is restored)
4. the sync process should be light-update - when possible update only the relevant changes and not all the information.

how would you start on building such a massive protocol? where should i save the data? 
Does anyone know of any framework that i can base my project on?

Answer (score 0):

How about looking at Live Mesh and its API for the file based types, http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other

and the Sync Framework for SQL or data types, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx

Comment: the link you supplied for live mesh - doesn't work for me. :\
i tried looking at the syn framework - but it seems missing api - i have tried to compile some sample code they provide and it doesnt even compile.

Answer (score 0):

What Sync Framework sample code wouldn't compile? We test everything we publish, but we might have missed something. It would help us to know so we can fix it!

You can also look at Code Gallery (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sync) for complete samples, if that works better for you.

Comment: i have downloaded a project called SharingAppDemo-CEPRoviderEndToEnd 
and it gives me compilation errors -SharingAppDemo-CEProviderEndToEnd\app\SynchronizationHelper.cs(33,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RelationalSyncProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: im not sure what versions does it actually use because i donwloaded the 2.1 framework and then tried to update it with the 4 ctp version...

Comment: Try removing the references to the four Microsoft.Synchronization assemblies and then re-adding the references. It should compile then.

Comment: This is an issue that happens when converting to Visual Studio 2010. Is this the version of VS you are using?